# How to generate intermediate tables from JPA2 models in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jpa-2.0

I have to objects, User and Company and they have a one to many relationship. A user can have multiple companies. I want to model this in a database using three tables. User, UserCompany and Company where the UserCompany links the two tables together.

In my java code however I don't want to 'see' this table. E.g in the User class I want to have a getCompanies() method which returns a list (or set) of Company objects.

I also want to use JPA2 and will be running the application in Glassfish in the EE6 container.
I've been playing with Eclipse (the Dali generation plugin) to generate the database tables but it will not generate any intermediate table.

Is this at all possible? If yes, can you give me an example of two classes with JPA2 annotations from which I can generate the three database tables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a simple case of RTFM. I copied the JoinColumn annotation from another class which is actually preventing a join table. I replaced it with a JoinTable annotation (which is not required but to keep the table and field names more logical I do use it) and now it works oke.